# Failed to copy gdb in ArcPy

Tags: copy, archive, arcpy

I am trying to archive a geodatabase into an Archive folder. The geodatabase is successfully copied into the Archive folder, but I receive an error code that prohibits the rest of my code from running. The error message is:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000260: Failed to copy C:\\Folder\\Geodatabase.gdb into C:\Folder\Archive\Archived_20161028.gdb
Failed to execute (Copy).
```

As mentioned, when I look in the Archive folder, the Geodatabase is stored there as Archived_20161028.gdb. I am not sure how to continue to run my code or why the error message is popping up.

```
import arcpy

import os 

Archive = r'C:\Folder\Archive' 
if not os.path.exists(Archive):
    os.makedirs(Archive)

gdb=r'C:\\Folder\\Geodatabase.gdb'
shp="C:\Folder\Geodatabase.gdb\Shapefile"


if len(gdb) > 0:
    print gdb
    fcArchived = os.path.join(Archive, 'Archived_{}.gdb'.format(time.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
    print fcArchived
    arcpy.Copy_management(gdb, fcArchived)

arcpy.Delete_management(gdb)

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management (r'C:\\Folder',"Geodatabase.gdb")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem!!!!  I have other scripts that have been using arcpy.Copy_management to copy/paste file geodatabases from one network location to another, but for some reason, a recent script I've been working on isn't working.

For this recent script, I do notice that you can use arcpy.Copy_management where the in_data parameter is from a network location and the out_data is a local location.  Then, using arcpy.Copy_management you can copy from this local location to a network location so long as the names of the file gdb's are identical.  This seems like a bug.

If you don't like the workaround above, here's another suggestion:
try:
    arcpy.Copy_management(copyfrom, copyto)
except:
    pass

I'll contact ESRI about this and see if they see the same thing....
...so heard from ESRI.

This is a bug (BUG-000093700).  Good news is that they say it's fixed at ArcGIS 10.4.

Comment: Yesssss the work around involving copying to local, then copying back to network solved my problem!!

Comment: I am having this problem too but could not solve it this way!